# Using a filter in part of a string

Tags: vue.js

I have a filter that formats a number based on what stat type it is (percent, integer, currency, etc).  I want to use this filter on a value as part of a string.  See below:

```
<js-widget
                v-on:click="this.selectedReportId = key"
                :selected="this.selectedReportId == key"
                :icon="report.icon"
                :stat="report.current | stat report.statType"
                :title="report.title"
                :tooltip="report.tooltip"
                :percent="report.percent"
                :description="'Previous value: '+(report.past | stat report.statType)">
</js-widget>
```

As you can see in the `:stat` parameter, I can use the filter if it is the only thing in the expression.  But when it tries to evaluate the `:description` parameter, I get `Error when evaluating expression`.  Is it possible to use a filter in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is something available outside of the expression you are evaluating – so that's not going to work syntactially

I would use a `computed` property instead. For more information, see http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have the widget component designed in a way that I could compute it within the component.  I just pass a string as the `description`.  I ended up making a method on the current component that build the string for me and used `Vue.filter('stat')` to fetch the filter.

Comment: You wouldn't make it a computed in the widget - you would do it in the parent component hosting the widget and then use it in the :description binding.

Comment: Since I have multiple reports, the `description` field is a nested property inside them. So I made a method `getReportDescription(report)`.  I guess are you suggesting I could make a `formattedReports` property that formats the whole array of reports?

Comment: Oh, as in you are iterating over a collection? Then a method based solution like you did is the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's been very long since the question was asked, but if someone searches, I happen to know the solution.
First there is a way to call a filter from inside the vue component. Actually all filters are stored in the

```
this.$options.filters
```

collection. So if you want to call a filter from inside the component you should do

```
...
this.$options.filters.stat(report.past, report.statType)
...
```

And if you want to do the same from the markup, you should also call filter not like filter (`|` syntax), but like the component method

```
<js-widget
                v-on:click="this.selectedReportId = key"
                :selected="this.selectedReportId == key"
                :icon="report.icon"
                :stat="report.current | stat report.statType"
                :title="report.title"
                :tooltip="report.tooltip"
                :percent="report.percent"
                :description="'Previous value: '+ $options.filters.stat(report.past, report.statType)">
</js-widget>
```

Or, better, with template string

```
:description = "`Previous value: ${$options.filters.stat(report.past, report.statType)}`"
```